# Formatar um bloco de variáveis do Terraform

Tags: cloud

Estou começando com Terraform e estou com uma dificuldade.

Tenho uma estrutura com vários valores de "key = value" então monto a seguinte estrutura no `variaveis.tf`

```
variable "environment" {

  type = list(object({

    key = string

    value  = string

  }))

  description = "The environment variables to pass to the container"

  default     = [porta = xxx, banco = mysql, password = zzzz]

}
```

Tem em torno de 8 chaves com valor como eu adiciono esta estrutura no arquivo qual o formato?

Answer (score 2):

Se quer declarar uma variável da maneira que descreveu na pergunta, poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
variable "config" {
  description = "Ambiente"
  default     = []
  type        = list(
    object({
      env     = string,
      porta   = number,
      usuario = string,
      nomedb  = string
    })
  )
}
```

Poderia declarar o atributo `default` da seguinte forma:

```
default = [{
      env = "development",
      porta = 12345,
      usuario = "admin",
      nomedb  = "fabrica"
}]
```

A versão "completa" ficaria assim:

```
variable "config" {
  description = "Ambiente"
  type = list(
    object({
      env = string,
      porta = number,
      usuario = string,
      nomedb  = string
    })
  )
  default     = [{
      env = "development",
      porta = 12345,
      usuario = "admin",
      nomedb  = "fabrica"
  },
  {
      env = "prod",
      porta = 12345,
      usuario = "admin",
      nomedb  = "fabrica-prod"
  }]
}
```

Depois para utilizar a variável `config` em seu `main.tf` você pode pode utilizar o `for .. each` da seguinte forma:

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length  = 64
  special = true
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "elasticache-auth-token" {
  for_each = {for instancia in var.config: instancia.env => instancia}

  name  = each.value.usuario
  type  = "SecureString"
  value = random_password.password.result
}
```

Aprenda como utilizar um [`foreach`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) no Terraform.

Após fazer esse ajuste, basta executar os comandos:

```
terraform plan
```

Verifique as mudanças e depois basta provisionar a infra-estrutura com o comando:

```
terraform apply
```